# ComboBox Re-sizing When UserPaint = true

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, onpaint

I am trying to paint over a ComboBox in winforms and I want to maintain the height of 21 but whenever I turn on userpaint, the height of the ComboBox increases to 24 and I am unable to change it.

```
    protected override void OnDropDownStyleChanged( EventArgs Args ) {

        base.OnDropDownStyleChanged( Args );
        SetStyle( ControlStyles.UserPaint, DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList );

    }
```

Commenting out the SetStyle line will make the height behave as it should but my overridden OnPaint method will not apply. Is there a way to paint over the ComboBox while still maintaining its original height of 21?

**(EDIT) I fixed it with this:**

```
    public CustomComboBox( ) {
        DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
    }
```

**(EDIT2) Now text isn't showing up on my dropdown list.**

**(EDIT3) Fixed again:**

fix found here: [OwnerDrawVariable Combobox DropDown Blank Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080931/ownerdrawvariable-combobox-dropdown-blank-space)

[ my version ]

```
    protected override void OnDrawItem( DrawItemEventArgs Args ) {

        Args.DrawBackground( );

        Int32 Index = Args.Index;

        if ( Index < 0 || Index >= Items.Count ) {
            return;
        }

        using ( Brush ItemBrush = new SolidBrush( Args.ForeColor ) ) {

            Rectangle ItemRectangle = new Rectangle( );
            ItemRectangle.X = Args.Bounds.Left;
            ItemRectangle.Y = Args.Bounds.Top + ( ( Args.Bounds.Height - ItemHeight ) / 2 );
            ItemRectangle.Width = Args.Bounds.Width;
            ItemRectangle.Height = ItemHeight;
            Args.Graphics.DrawString( Items[ Args.Index ].ToString( ), Args.Font, ItemBrush, ItemRectangle );

        }

        Args.DrawFocusRectangle( );
        return;

    }
```

Comment: Yes, you told the control that you would take care of the drawing part now.  You have work to do.

Comment: yep ^.^

I edited my post again with the code I used to solve the problem again (with reference from a different post).